# NPM Run Build The Syntax of command is incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Using this tutorial: http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/step-by-step-environment-setup-of-the-react-developer-no-legacy-2016-standards/ I encountered a vague error after typing `npm run build`.

If you seen my previous question the package.json only has a slight variation and I suspect its something to do with these lines (the spaces in the file/directory names): `"build": "webpack -d && copy src/app/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --colors --progress --content-base src/",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p && copy src/app/index.html dist/index.html"`

But I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Thank-you.

package.json code

```
{
    "name": "rapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "\"\"",
    "main": "index.js",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "\"\""
    },
    "keywords": [
        "\"\""
    ],
    "author": "\"BH0\"",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "webpack": "^2.6.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "babel": "babel", 
        "webpack": "webpack", 

        "build": "webpack -d && copy src/app/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --colors --progress --content-base src/",
        "build-prod": "webpack -p && copy src/app/index.html dist/index.html"
    }
}
```

[Error message after typing 'npm run build'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd7Xo.png)

webpack.config.js:

```js
var path = require('path');

var DIST_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' );
var SOURCE_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, 'src' );

module.exports = {
    entry: SOURCE_PATH + '/app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: DIST_PATH,   
        filename: 'app.dist.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },  
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,  
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        'es2015',
                        'react',
                        'stage-2'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Please forgive me for poor formatting but it wasn't working (my laptop's track-pad damaged).

Comment: It failed at copying assets, can you make sure that your folder/file paths are correct in webpack config file.

Comment: @Niraj I have submitted the webpack.config file but since I am new to React I don't think I can confirm that the paths are correct, I also copied the code from the tutorial and I don't quite understand it, could you please revisit this question? Also feel free to re-format it correctly, sorry

Answer (score 5):

You have to change all your file path to this `\\`. I tested your code, it is working fine.

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require( "webpack" ),
path = require ( "path" );

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve( __dirname, "dist" ),
    SRC_DIR = path.resolve ( __dirname, "src" );

var config = {

    entry: SRC_DIR + "\\app\\index.js",

    output: {

        path: DIST_DIR + "\\app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "\\app\\"

    },

    module: {

        loaders: [{

            test: /\.js?/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: { presets: [ "env", "react", "stage-2" ] }

        }]

    }

}

module.exports = config;

// package.json
"scripts": {

    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && copy src\\index.html dist\\index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src\\ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && copy src\\index.html dist\\index.html"

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this exact issue, and found the solution at - https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-basics/issues/13 
I know it is too late, but the logic is that when we hit the "npm run build" command, it goes to "package.json" file and picks up the "build" parameters from the "script" block. The given "build" parameters includes folder location using forward slash (/), which doesn't work in windows OS. That needs to be replaced with double backward slash (`\\`). That solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your copy command is incorrect.

```
copy src/app/index.html dist/index.html
```

This is having some problem, I am not a windows user so cant test it, just make sure that the file structure & paths are correct. Looking at your screenshot the webpack command was successsful, the next command was `copy`, which is failing.